# ios6 - How to present a login screen before uisplitviewcontroller?

Tags: authentication, ios6, uisplitviewcontroller

I'm developing an app with a UISplitViewController. However, I need to show a Login Screen before the UISPlitViewController. I created a simple UIViewController and I created a segue from the DetailViewController to the new UIViewController. I also created a ViewDidAppear in DetailViewController who calls the segue.

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
```

{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];

```
       [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loginSegue" sender:self];
```

}

I got this error: "has no segue with identifier 'loginSegue'"

Are there any great way to do this?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found the solution myself. The solution is: call a modal inside applicationDidBecomeActive in AppDelegate. Example:

```
static dispatch_once_t onceToken;

dispatch_once( &onceToken, ^
              {
                  UIStoryboard *storyboard = self.window.rootViewController.storyboard;
                  LoginViewController* launchViewController = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"LoginViewController"];
                  [self.window.rootViewController presentViewController:launchViewController animated:NO completion:NULL];

                  launchViewController.managedObjectContext = self.managedObjectContext;
              } );
```